# Efficiently remove a bootable partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to know what technically happens when you remove a partition with gparted.

I want to get rid of my windows partition in an efficient way. However, is it better to delete or to format it? Also, do I need to edit any boot files to let grub know there's no windows partition anymore?

Comment: What does "efficient" mean? A partition is just a chunk of disk space; what you use it for depends on your plans. Deleting a partition simply marks that chunk of disk space as unused; if you want to make that disk space available you must decide *how* you want to make it available. And yes absolutely you must `sudo update-grub` afterwards; if the boot disk is formatted with the GPT partitioning scheme you may also need to inform the system firmware about the change.

Comment: Maybe efficient isn't the word. I don't understand if it's better to "mark" a disk space as unused or to clear it with zero's (I don't know if it's possible). How would I "inform" the system firmware?

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of my Windows partition?" Do you want to keep the partition for re-use? Or do you want to give the freed space to other partitions?

Comment: I don't use windows, so I want to give its space to my data partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk (be it a spinning disk or a solid-state disk) storage space is made up of logical sectors, which are numbered from zero to some large number. In Linux, this complete space is seen for example as `/dev/sda`.

In most cases the disk contais a [partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table), which divides this space into contiguous portions named partitions. (Some operating systems and software programs prefer the term "disk label" instead of partition table.) Even if you want to use all the space as one unbroken chunk it is still recommended to place a partition table on the disk, even if it describes only one partition; this is because most software expects disks to contain partition tables. Continuing the example, the partitions will be seen in Linux as `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2` etc.

There two kinds of partition tables in widespread use, one named [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) (for Master Boot Record) and the other [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) (for GUID Partition Table; a GUID is a Globally Unique IDentifier).

- Boot disks which are used for booting systems in BIOS mode (sometimes seen as "legacy mode" in system configuration screens) must use the MBR partitioning scheme.
- Boot disks which are used for booting systems in [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) mode must use the GPT partitioning scheme.
- Data disks up to 2 TB capacity can use either MBR or GPT, at the pleasure of the administrators.
- Data disks of more than 2 TB must use the GPT partitioning scheme (because the MBR partition table cannot reliably describe partitions beyond the 2 TB limit).

Deleting a partition means deleting an entry in the partition table. (Actually, the entry is not really deleted, because partition tables have a fixed size; the entry is marked as unusued.)

When you delete a partition which used to contain a bootable operating system you must tell the boot loader to stop trying to boot it. In Linux you use `update-grub` for this purpose. If the system boots in UEFI mode then you must also tell the UEFI firmware to stop trying to boot the now deleted partition; how you do this depends on the specific computer system you have.

Remember that partitions are *contiguous* portions of disk space. When you delete a partition you can immediately allocate its space to its neighbour on the left, because all that neighbour has to do is to update its ending boundary. If you want to allocate the space to the neighbour on the right then you must use a specialized utility able to move the existing data, because space in a partition is addressed starting from zero.

For example, suppose we have four partitions occupying the disk space like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| /dev/sda1 | /dev/sda2 | /dev/sda4 | /dev/sda3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

(Note that the partition numbers are not in order; this is intentional, in order to show that there is no necessary relationship between the position of the partitions on disk and their number.)

Suppose we delete partition 2. The disk space becomes:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| /dev/sda1 | (Unused)  | /dev/sda4 | /dev/sda3 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

- We can extend `/dev/sda1` into the unused space; this is easy and immediate.
- If we want to allocate the disk space to `/dev/sda4` then we must *move* `/dev/sda4` into the unused space; this takes time and requires specialized software.
- If we want to allocate the disk space to `/dev/sda3` then we must first move `/dev/sda4` without changing its size, and *then* move `/dev/sda3` into the new space.